# NextJS passed function is not a function

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to pass a function from a parent function to a child function but I'm getting

```
TypeError: setVoiceInput is not a function
```

Parent Code:

```
// questionInput.js
"use client";

import styles from './questionInput.module.css';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";
import Upload from "@/components/upload";
import Voice from "@/components/voice";

const QuestionInput = ({addToInputList, addToResponseList}) => {

    const [question, setQuestion] = useState("");

    const setVoiceInput = (voice) => {
        setQuestion(voice)
    }

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setQuestion(event.target.value);
    };

    const addInput = (input) => {
        addToInputList(input);

    };

    const addResponse = (response) => {
        addToResponseList(response);
    }


    const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        addInput(question)

        const fetchData = async () => {
            try {
                const url = "/api/ask-gpt";
                const response = await fetch(url, {
                    method: "POST",
                    headers: {
                        "Content-Type": "application/json",
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify({question}),
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error("Request failed with status: " + response.status);
                }


                const data = await response.json();
                addResponse(data)

            } catch (error) {
                console.error("Error fetching data:", error);

            }
        };

        await fetchData();

        setQuestion("");
    };


    return (
        <div className={styles.main}>

            <Upload/>
            <Voice setVoiceInput={setVoiceInput}/>

            <form id={'csv-input'} onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={styles.container}>
                <input type="text" value={question} onChange={handleChange}
                       placeholder={"Ask a question about your CSV."} className={styles.input}/>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
};

export default QuestionInput;
```

child function:

```
// voice.js
"use client"

import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime'
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import SpeechRecognition, { useSpeechRecognition } from 'react-speech-recognition';

const Voice = ({setVoiceInput}) => {
    console.log('test')

    const [speechRecognitionSupported, setSpeechRecognitionSupported] = useState(null)

    const {
        transcript,
        listening,
        resetTranscript,
        browserSupportsSpeechRecognition
    } = useSpeechRecognition();

    useEffect(() => {
        setSpeechRecognitionSupported(browserSupportsSpeechRecognition)
    }, [browserSupportsSpeechRecognition])


    useEffect(() => {
        setVoiceInput(transcript);
    }, [transcript, setVoiceInput, browserSupportsSpeechRecognition])


    if (speechRecognitionSupported === null) return null

    if (!speechRecognitionSupported) {
        return <span>Browser does not support speech recognition.</span>
    }



    return (
        <div>
            <p>Microphone: {listening ? 'on' : 'off'}</p>
            <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.startListening}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={SpeechRecognition.stopListening}>Stop</button>
            <button onClick={resetTranscript}>Reset</button>
        </div>
    );
};
export default Voice;
```

I've made sure that there are no prop errors and that the names are the same.

I've tried console.log(setVoiceInput) on the voice and I found out that the voice component runs multiple times. The first time it has the function but the other times it is undefined. Here is an example:

```
(function here)
undefined
undefined
(function here)
```

Edit: I found the solution! I accidentally called the component elsewhere.

Comment: Have you tried to pass the setQuestion function straight to the Voice component, like so <Voice setVoiceInput={setQuestion}/>
The setVoiceInput gets redeclared every render, and that would cause the Voice useEffect to fire on every rerender of the parent component. An alternative would be to useCallback the setVoiceInput, it's a good practice if functions are passed down and used in effects, to useCallback since that will make your function stay the same between rerenders

Comment: @MattiSig I've tried both and still get the same problem unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing dependency array in useEffect might work!!

Comment: What should I change it to?